# How to sort object in JavaScript based on date

Tags: javascript

**Input Data**

```
 var data =  {
    "36905b7cb": "(2019-12-26 T 13H-39M-0S) Co-Testing",
    "cad5dd7ea": "(2019-12-05 T 16H-38M-9S) Diagnosis",
    "sad4217ea": "(2020-03-05 T 16H-38M-9S) Bio-Testing"
  }
```

**Expected Output**

```
var data =  {
    "sad4217ea": "(2020-03-05 T 16H-38M-9S) Bio-Testing"
    "36905b7cb": "(2019-12-26 T 13H-39M-0S) Co-Testing",
    "cad5dd7ea": "(2019-12-05 T 16H-38M-9S) Diagnosis"
  }
```

we have to arrange the data in the sorted based on date.**Not the KEYS**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Comment: Are you sure that you need it to be an object not an Array?
Because the keys of an Object are not ordered

Comment: @ManishSundriyal in JS you have keys order guaranteed by the spec so it's safe to use. It means that you can iterate over object keys in the order they were added

Comment: @ManishSundriyal we have an object in which to order data based on date.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I know that, but the thing is we cannot order keys of an Object.

Comment: @RahulSaini Can you share what you want to do with the sorted object?
Maybe we can give a different solution to it. Because we cannot sort the keys of an Object. It is generally sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: @ManishSundriyal Oh, ok, I see what you mean now. You said that *"keys are not ordered"* so I referred to that.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Sorry, for the confusion.

Comment: @ManishSundriyal Only I want to show sorted data in the view(Front side).

Comment: @RahulSaini that's fine. But how you will be using it? Are you showing a list?

Comment: Yes I'm showing a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array util functions like `reduce`, `sort`.
[image]

Comment: if data = { "787": "(2019-12-04 T 21H-17M-0S) Ortho 1",
    "456": "(2019-12-04 T 23H-58M-0S) Cardiologist Research",
    "123": "(2019-12-05 T 19H-0M-0S) Survey shoot 2",
    "36905b7cb": "(2019-12-26 T 13H-39M-0S) Co-Testing",
    "cad5dd7ea": "(2019-12-05 T 16H-38M-9S) Diagnosis",
    "sad4217ea": "(2020-03-05 T 16H-38M-9S) Bio-Testing"}



Its not working on this input.Please help me